# How to change the text of Go to Checkout button in minicart?

Tags: magento2.1.13

I want to change text

> "go to checkout" to "Get it now"

in the minicart.
Can anyone help me to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

To change text only in Minicart wrapper you have to change text in template/minicart/content.html

copy below file to your theme file and then change the text :

**From :**

> /vendor/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html

**To your theme folder :**

> /PackageName/theme-name/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html

**NOTE** : after update clear your cache and deploy static-content again.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the translation file in your theme

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/module-checkout/i18n

From the CSV replace the text "Go to checkout" text to "Get it now"

Then run the following command

```
1. rm -fr pub/static/frontend/*
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy 
3. php bin/magento cache:clean
4. php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is do this from admin setting Inline Translation:

**admin->Advanced->Developer->Translation Inline and changed "Enabled for Storefront" to YES** after that change "go to checkout" to  "Get it now" as required text.After doing this,disable translation from admin again.

Refer image to change settings from admin:

[image]

Let me know if you need any help.